# How do I check multiple folders and delete any files with unique file names?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, delete-file

I'm capturing images of widgets off of multiple cameras on an inspection system. If the inspection is unsuccessful, the image doesn't get saved. The images are named with the widget's serial number.

So my folder structure might look like

- Camera1

  - 1.tif
  - 2.tif
  - 4.tif
- Camera2

  - 2.tif
  - 3.tif
  - 4.tif
- Camera3

  - 1.tif
  - 2.tif
  - 3.tif
  - 4.tif

I want to be able to delete images that don't have a match in all three folders. I don't mind running the solution twice, once between camera1 and camera2, and then again using camera2 and camera 3.

I'm hoping to only be left with the following folder structure.

- Camera1

  - 2.tif
  - 4.tif
- Camera2

  - 2.tif
  - 4.tif
- Camera3

  - 2.tif
  - 4.tif

There are ~12,000 files in each folder for analysis and probably 2%-3% erroneous which need to be removed to continue analysis.

I don't mind prepackaged solutions requiring payment, python, command line, etc.

Thanks much!

Comment: first you have to read all filenames. Next you should use this filenames to create dictionary with lists like `{"1.tif":["Camera1", "Camera3"], "2.tif":[...]}` and next you should check which filenames has less then 3 values on list and then you can delete theses filenames from these folders.

Comment: Since the number of files won't cause issues if you load a few lists in memory, how about creating 3 sets with the contents of the folders, determining the intersection of those three sets, and then removing that intersection from the original lists. That way, you have three sets left that tell you exactly what files you need to remove in each folder.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, next time you ask something on SO, have a shot at it yourself first, and ask about any problems - you learn more that way.

Here's a start, as suggested the code below creates 3 sets with the contents of the folders, determines the intersection of those three sets, and then removes that intersection from the original sets. The result tells you exactly what files you need to remove in each folder:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def find_unmatched(dirs):
    # list the (file) contents of the folders
    contents = {}
    for d in dirs:
        contents[d] = set(str(n.name) for n in Path(d).glob('*') if n.is_file())

    # decide what the folders have in common
    all_files = list(contents.values())
    common = all_files[0]
    for d_contents in all_files[1:]:
        common = common.intersection(d_contents)

    # create a dictionary that tells you what to remove
    return {d: files - common for d, files in contents.items()}


to_remove = find_unmatched(['photos/Camera1', 'photos/Camera2', 'photos/Camera3'])
print(to_remove)
```

Result (given the folders in your example sit in a folder called `photos`):

```
{'photos/Camera1': {'1.tif'}, 'photos/Camera2': {'3.tif'}, 'photos/Camera3': {'1.tif', '3.tif'}}
```

Actually removing the files is some code you can probably figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you should do your own efforts to solve the problem and just ask for help when you get stuck. However, I have some spare time now, so I wrote a complete Batch solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process files in Camera1 folder and populate "F" array elements = 1
cd Camera1
for %%a in (*.tif) do set "F[%%~Na]=1"

rem Process files in Camera2 and *accumulate* files to "F" array
cd ..\Camera2
for %%a in (*.tif) do set /A "F[%%~Na]+=1"

rem Process files in Camera3 and accumulate files to "F" array
rem if counter == 3 then file is OK: remove "F" element
rem else: delete file
rem       if counter == 1: remove "F" element

cd ..\Camera3
for %%a in (*.tif) do (
   set /A "F[%%~Na]+=1"
   if !F[%%~Na]! equ 3 (
      set "F[%%~Na]="
   ) else (
      del %%a
      if !F[%%~Na]! equ 1 set "F[%%~Na]="
   )
)

rem Remove files of "F" array in both Camera1 and Camera2 folders, ignoring error messages
cd ..
(for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set F[') do (
   del Camera1\%%a.tif
   del Camera2\%%a.tif
)) 2>nul
```

Please, report the result...

Comment: Hey @Aacini, 

This worked like a charm. Created three folders of the same names from the script and populated with a subset of the work, ran the script unedited and they all came out perfect. Thanks for the help!

Also, I have absolutely learned my lesson in terms of showing my previous work! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Be warned that Batch files have speed problems with large number of environments variables. Run this program with your ~12000 files and check elapsed time. Perhaps it will take too much time and would be necessary to modify the method...

Comment: Hey @Aacini, it took about 3 minutes to parse through the 12K files. Again, thank you very much for your time, worked great!

Comment: May I ask you a favour? Could you run the same set of files with the other method of mine here (the one based on files) and compare the timing? This point is important for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the fastest though a quite simple method:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change into root directory:
pushd "%~dp0." && (
    rem // Outer loop through target directories:
    for /D %%J in ("Camera?") do (
        rem // Create temporary file with matching contents of current directory:
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%%~J\*.tif" > "%TEMP%\%%~nxJ.log"
        rem // Inner loop through target directories:
        for /D %%I in ("Camera?") do (
            rem // Avoid comparing current directory with itself:
            if /I not "%%~I"=="%%~J" (
                rem /* List these files inside of the directory of the inner loop where no
                rem    respective files inside of the directory of the outer loop are found: */
                for /F "delims= eol=|" %%K in ('
                    dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%%~I\*.tif" ^| findstr /L /I /V /G:"%TEMP%\%%~nxJ.log"
                ') do (
                    rem // Actually delete current file:
                    ECHO del "%%~I\%%K"
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Delete temporary file:
        del "%TEMP%\%%~nxJ.log"
    )
    rem // Return from root directory:
    popd
)
exit /B
```

The key is two nested loops over the target directories in order to compare each one with each other, and the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) used to filter out files from one directory that do not exist in the other one.

After having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command**!

Answer (score 0):

This new method is based on text files, so it should run faster than the environment variables method. The heavy task of search missing names in 12000 lines files (6 times!) is performed by `findstr` command.

This method is also simpler and allows to match more than 3 folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a list of directories and create temp files with their contents
set "directories="
for /D %%d in (Camera?) do (
   set "directories=!directories! %%d"
   dir /B "%%d\*.tif" > %%d.txt
)

rem Process the directories "d"
for %%d in (%directories%) do (

   rem Compare this directory "d" vs. the others "D"
   for %%D in (!directories:%%d=!) do (

      rem Remove files in this "d" that not exists in the other "D"
      (for /F %%f in ('findstr /V /G:%%D.txt %%d.txt') do del "%%d\%%f") 2>nul

   )

)

for %%d in (%directories%) do del %%d
```